# How do I combine data frames in one data frame of very specific format in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, stock

I have a data frame for the stocks of coca cola and tesla and have only its daily returns and daily volatility and want to make a new dataframe that is organized in such that it will two columns, "Daily Returns" and "Daily Volatility" and an index "ID" which will either be TSLA or KO depending on what stock the value belongs too however I have had zero luck in doing so. Here is what I have so far:

```
    
    #Make modifiable variables
    tesla = teslaData # teslaData = dr.get_data_yahoo(teslaStock, start='2021-01-01', end='2021-12-31')

    cc = cocaData # dr.get_data_yahoo(cocacolaStock, start='2021-01-01', end='2021-12-31')
    
    #Get the required data from Coca-Cola
    cc['Daily_Returns_KO'] = cc['Close'].pct_change()
    cc['Daily_Volatility_KO'] = cc['Daily_Returns_KO'].rolling(window_size).std() * np.sqrt(252)
    
    #Get the required data from Tesla
    tesla['Daily_Returns_TSLA'] = tesla['Close'].pct_change()
    tesla['Daily_Volatility_TSLA'] = tesla['Daily_Returns_TSLA'].rolling(window_size).std() * np.sqrt(252)

    #Drop unneeded data, only keep daily returns and volatility
    cc = cc.drop(['High','Low','Open','Close','Volume','Adj Close'], axis = 1)
    tesla = tesla.drop(['High','Low','Open','Close','Volume','Adj Close'], axis = 1)
    
    #Give ID's to cc and tesla
    cc['ID'] = 'KO'
    cc.set_index("ID", inplace=True)
    tesla['ID'] = 'TSLA'
    tesla.set_index("ID", inplace=True)
    
    
    # #Concat the data frames into table
    # frames = [cc,tesla]
    # table = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=False,axis=0)
```

I tried to concat the data and modify a table from there but that lead nowhere, I tried to use stack however I couldnt use the query() command which I need for later. How would I be able to organize my data as described above?

Comment: What is the output of concat? I assume it gives you unwanted 4 columns?

Comment: Yes, it will give me the ID's as expected but 4 columns that are just the columns I made in the code above.

Comment: I think you should have the same column names when merging the `cc` and `tesla` frames. otherwise, there is no way for pandas to know the structure that you want. 
Daily_Returns_KO and Daily_Returns_TSLA --> `Daily_Returns` and  same for the other

Comment: @Fnaxiom I feel like such an idiot for not even trying that, thats all I needed, thank you.